# Pandas - Comparing Two Csv Dataframes but one csv has issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv dataframes and what I am trying to do is find the unique Login Ids that are not contained in dataframes two. The issue I am facing is that the following code runs but the df3 is returning all the rows and columns from df1. I suspect there is an issue with one of the rows in the df1 but this is where I need your help please to ascertain what may be causing this.

There are around 24000 rows in df1 and around 8500 in df2. When I get df3 it returns all the 24000 rows from df1 which I know is not correct as there are common logins between the two. Note the logins in df2 are under the column 'User Number'. My code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

fileLocationDf1 = "corpscore.csv"
fileLocationDf2 = "ENFI.csv"

createDf1 = pd.read_csv(fileLocationDf1)
createDf2 = pd.read_csv(fileLocationDf2, low_memory = False)

df3 = createDf1[~createDf1['login'].isin(createDf2['User Number'])]

df3.to_excel('Results.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Results')
```

Comment: provide some sample data.

Comment: Make sure that dtypes are matching, `low_memory=False` may skip some type casting, therefore you may end up comparing 'object' with 'int' or so in `isin`, and you get all `False` for indexing.

Comment: Also check `df3.dtypes`, your series may not be of the same types, e.g. `int` vs `str` can't compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your data. It might be that your data types are different.

See the example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2','5','6']})

df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]
#   A
#0  1
#2  3
```

And this one:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2','5a','6a'],
                    'B': list('def'),
                    'C': [1.7,0.3,2.8]})
df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]
#   A
#0  1
#1  2
#2  3
```

What is happening here is that `.isin()` is trying to convert the ***whole*** series within `.isin()` to same `dtype` as the one you are calling it for - and then does the comparison.

Comment: Perfect - the df2 had some logins which were strings... Many thanks for your help. It worked...